# Remove all XMLHTTP request CORS errors with the easiest way?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a webpage which helps people to have http requests,the javascript code looked like this:

```js
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        apply(this.responseText);//Show the response text on html element
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://google.com", true);
    xhttp.send();
```

And of course I've got this annoying error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://google.com/?safe=active&ssui=on' (redirected from 'https://google.com/') from origin 'MYWEBSITE' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

### Can I fix this **WITHOUT** any backend codes(or with the least backend code)(as my webpage is a client side webpage)?

Comment: Well if you're doing an HTTP request, it's not a (completely) client-side page. And no, you cannot "fix" it; it's fundamental web security.

Comment: Google doesn't allow you to request from this website, so you have to ask Google  ...or create a server-side proxy on your end, so it's no longer a browser sending the request.